# Copying data from azure table storage for the past 30 days

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

We are in a process of migrating our manually managed production environment to Terraform and in the process would be creating all the resources required for the environment anew. One of such resource is storage account.

We have a storage account that has close to 1500+ tables and each table consisting of millions of records with a timestamp attached to each of these records. During the migration we are mostly interested in copying the records for the past 30 days.

I was wondering if there's a tool that could help us perform this copy operation most effectively and which is less time consuming.

We looked into Azcopy but it only allows us to do one to one copy and copying billions of records might take us days and from what I learnt online Azcopy doesn't support queries to only copy days from a certain timestamp.

Would be helpful to get some insights on different tools and techniques we could adapt to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you found any better solution?

Comment: @IvanYang Thank you for your response. I did the following:

* Used Azure data factory to do a one to one copy from the beginning, which took almost 80 hours to run
* Created a C# app using the cosmos DB library mentioned here: https://paulomarquesc.github.io/working-with-azure-storage-tables-from-powershell/ to copy the delta (data added during the execution of Data factory job) 
*

Comment: Ok, you can share your solution by posting an answer:)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such the tools that can copy table storage from a specified timestamp. You should write your own logic to select from the specified timestamp, but that would cause bad performance.

Here, I suggest you can use a tool named [EastFive.Azure.Storage.Backup](https://github.com/eastfivellc/EastFive.Azure.Storage.Backup#eastfiveazurestoragebackup). It supports copy azure blob / azure table storage to a new storage account. And for azure table storage, it supports copy array of specified partition_key but not supports specified timestamp.

If you're interesting about it, you can follow the simple steps as below:

1.Create a folder named "backup" in D drive, then download all the 4 projects mentioned in [Prerequisites](https://github.com/eastfivellc/EastFive.Azure.Storage.Backup#prerequisites) into D:\backup.

2.Unzip all the 4 projects, and open them one by one in visual studio -> in the manage nuget package in visual studio, updates all the old packages -> build them one by one, make sure each of them are built successfully.

3.Open the **backup.json** in EastFive.Azure.Storage.Backup project, fill in your `sourceConnectionString` and `targetConnectionString`.

If you don't want to copy blobs, just remove blobs.

For `timeLocal` field at the end, it means when to run the copy activity according to your local time.

4.You can [install it as a service](https://github.com/eastfivellc/EastFive.Azure.Storage.Backup#installing), and start the service to run the copy activity.

I test it at my side, and all of my azure table storage are copied to the new storage account, a screenshot as below:

[image]